# How do I create a Heads-up format notification that can't be dismissed until interacted with

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-notifications

I'd like to create a vibrating notification that won't stop until the user dismisses it, exactly like the standard android Timer bundled with the OS.

I'd also like it to appear on the lock screen.

The below gets me some of the way there but it does not appear on the lock screen and I haven't got a dismiss button.

Two main questions, how do I create a dismiss button and how do I ensure this displays on the lock screen?

```
public void CountdownAlarm()
    {
        var style = new Android.App.Notification.BigTextStyle();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        PendingIntent piDismiss = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .SetContentTitle("Audio Tour")
            .SetContentText("The second part is about to begin. Please get ready.")
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
            .SetCategory(Notification.CategoryAlarm)
            //.SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.All)
            .SetVibrate(new long[0])
            .SetStyle(style)
            .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.Max)
            .SetOngoing(true)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetVisibility(NotificationVisibility.Public)
            .SetFullScreenIntent(piDismiss, true);

        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        notificationManager.Notify(121212, builder.Build());
    }
```

Comment: What's you mean `a dismiss button`, an additional button on your notification?

Comment: Hi @YorkShen-MSFT thanks for looking at my questions. As it might be that I can have control over cancelling timers from the alarm clock class I'm looking to recreate the 'egg timer' style alarm bundled with android OS that has a dismiss button when it reaches down to zero. It also appears on the lock screen. It feels slightly like reinventing the wheel but could give me fine control over it.

Comment: I feel that the real question should be how do create and cancel timers in android